# Where do conda and pip get their packages from?

Tags: python, pip, package, repository, conda

I have the anaconda python distribution on my work PC, and would like to install new packages onto this. I do this regularly at home, but am unable to do it at work.

My company supports strict IT security policies, and users don't have admin rights to their PCs. I suspect this is why the package managers pip and conda both seem to have been locked down (probably through the firewall). I have asked our IT guys to unlock access to the package managers temporarily, so that I can install a couple of packages that I need for an upcoming project.

They've asked me which software repositories they need to unblock. Presumably these are different for pip and conda, but I don't know how to capture this information.

Can someone please advise?

Cheers,

B

Comment: Does your IT dept have a dev ops team?  These teams normally have a suite of tools and processes that have been security tested,  passed all policy requirements,  pen tested etc

Comment: To distinguish missing admin rights from network blockage, can you confirm to have installed your python environment under your user only? We had similar issues at work when Anaconda was installed system-wide ... don't do that.